# S3 Restricted Bucket Progressive Download

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, progressive-download

I have videos stored in a restricted bucket on Amazon S3. Once a user logs into their account, viewing the video page will generate a signed url for a given video, allowing it to be viewed via progressive download.

The videos are variable in length; some are just a few minutes long, and some are as long as ten minutes. Initially, I had set the signed urls' timeout to be five minutes, but as some of the videos are longer than that, customers were seeing the videos getting cut off. As a result, I increased the signed url timeout to be as longer than the longest video.

I would like to know if it's possible for me to set the timeout back down to a shorter amount, instead allowing the videos to call a new signed url in order to get the next chunk of the progressive download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard video players have **no concept of Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs**, so they would not be able to "call back" to your application to request a new URL. You could write your own video player (based off Open Source code), but that would be a lot of work for this little benefit.

When your application generates the pre-signed URL, it could take a look at the length of the video (somehow, perhaps via metadata or an estimate based on the size of the object) and **set the expiration time accordingly**.

You might also want to investigate serving video files via [Amazon CloudFront RTMP distributions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html). CloudFront can provide security via pre-signed URLs and also [signed cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html). It would be more difficult for people to download content from an RTMP distribution than an Amazon S3 bucket.